# Collection returned by .where not responding as expected

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I'm trying to define a new array through a where query but I can only get it to work one way.

Here it is:

```
<%   

 @children = Array.new
 Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id).each do |y|
     @children.push(y.name)
 end


 return @children
 %>


 Returns the array ["Performance Arts", "Visual Arts", "Physical Arts", "Music", "Culinary Arts"] (All topics)
```

But I would prefer just to do

```
  @children = Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id)

  return @children.each.name

  Returns "undefined method `name' for #<Enumerator:0x007fe92205a1f0>"
```

For whatever reason .each won't respond correctly... although it works on the initial where call in the first example. What's the difference?

and Is there a way to do this so that I can pull the names directly through the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #where method returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object, not an array.

To get an array, call #all or #to_a on it:

```
@children = Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id).all
@children = Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id).to_a
```

Note that you don't need to convert it to an array in order to iterate over it.

Check out Frederick Cheung's answer to why your use of #each doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Lars. I was stuck on this for about 2 hours.

Comment: You cannot call `Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id).to_a.name` either, there is no issue with ActiveRecord::Relation here.

Answer (score 3):

That's just not what `each` does. You might be looking for `map` (or its alias), `collect`

```
Topic.where(...).map {|topic| topic.name}
```

You can make that a little shorter using the Symbol#to_proc shortcut:

```
Topic.where(...).map &:name
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with either of those. I'll have to test them out and read up on them.

Answer (score 2):

On Rails 3.2 there's also `pluck`:

```
@children = Topic.where(breadcrumb_id: @topic.id).pluck("name")
```

This has the extra benefit of doing a `SELECT name FROM ...` instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: I'd forgotten about pluck! It also looks like it doesn't actually instantiate any active record objects so should be slightly faster than `Topic.select('name').map(&:name)`